# Python datetime - For each value in a list subtract 10 days from current datetime

Tags: python, dataframe, time

Hello I have a list of stock prices and would like to make a new list of dates fitting the stock prices.
The plan for the dates list is that each value in the list will be the date - 10 days from the date before. Example [2020-07-17, 2020-07-7, 2020-06-27, 2020-06-17...]

```
df_historical = pd.DataFrame(realtimePrices)
historical_chart = df_historical.iloc[:, -1]

historical_chart_list = historical_chart.tolist()
price_history = historical_chart_list[0::10]
print(price_history)

b = datetime.date.today()
print(b)
tdelta = datetime.timedelta(days=10)



time_list = []
for i in range(len(price_history)):
    time_list.append(b-What should I type here to get the list to work)
```

Comment: Half an hour has passed and no one else has given any advice, so I will take a crack at it. It should be easy enough. I don't have your data sets but that shouldn't be a problem. I can give you an example of the methods and you can adapt them to your need. Check back later. I'm in the middle of fixing dinner and can't tackle the examples right now. In short, there is a date/time class that supports subtraction, and we may be able to use the map() function to apply that subtraction to every member of the list.

Comment: `time_list.append(b - i*tdelta)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this example helps. I was a little confused by your list of dates as I did not know what type of data each item was. The most logical assumption is that each is a string and I worked on that bases.

```
from datetime import *

def str_2_datetime(st): # Converts a string to a datetime Class object.
    return datetime.strptime(st,"%Y-%m-%d")
# -------------
def rollback(date): # Subtracts seven days from a given date
    interval = timedelta(days = 7)
    return date - interval
# ==============
#    Main()
# --------------
# First I need to create a list based on the example data you gave me.
# I will assume those dates are strings and convert them to the
# date_time class.

date_list = []
data = ["2020-07-17", "2020-07-7", "2020-06-27", "2020-06-17"]

hold = map(str_2_datetime,data) # Map() applies a function to each elemnt. 
date_list = list(hold) # Convert the map object to a list we can use.

# Show the list of dates we will be working with.
print('',"="*60)
print("      Test Data:")
for elm in date_list:
    print(' ',elm)
print('',"="*60,end="\n")

# Now that we have a list of dates, we can roll each back by 7 days.

hold = map(rollback,date_list) # Map our function to each date.
# (Yes, you could increment through each element with a for loop,
#  but I'm enchanted with the map() method. It is so handy!)
back_list = list(hold) # Convert map object to a list we can use.

print("     Finish Data:")
for elm in back_list:
    print('',elm)
print('',"="*60,end="\n\n")
exit()
```